# Can a ATG project can be deployed in Apache Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, atg, oracle-commerce

I created a simple project using **ATG 10.2** .I want to know whether it can be deployed in **Apache Tomcat** Server?.If yes How to deploy it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is technically possible to deploy to Tomcat. It is not a simple process to do so. More importantly the only supported Application Servers for ATG 10.2 are:

- JBOSS 5.1.2 EAP
- Weblogic 10.3.5 and 10.3.6
- WAS 7.0.0.25

Either way, in the event that you are trying to do testing against your application, it is advisable to do so in an environment that mirrors your production environment so if you are running, for example, JBOSS in production, you should run JBOSS in your pre-production environments too.